# complex numbers for quadratic equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Find the quadratic equation whose roots are $2+i$ and $3-i$.

$$\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Comment: $(x-(2+i))(x-(3-i))$ will give you the equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a, b$ are roots of a quadratic equation, then the quadratic equation can be written as

$$(x-a)(x-b) = 0$$

This is intuitively true because substituting in either of the roots $a,b$ will cause LHS to yield $0$.

If you want a more rigorous proof, this result is known as the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem), which states that any entire function can be represented by a product involving its zeroes.

In your case, this is just 
$$(x-(2+i))(x-(3-i)) = 0$$

You can expand it out if you want it in the form $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$.

A shortcut to the expansion would be to notice that $(x-a)(x-b) = x^2 - (a + b)x + ab$. The coefficient of $x$ is negative of the sum of the roots, while the term independent of $x$ is the product of the roots. This concept is further generalized to higher degree polynomials with [Vieta's Formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: but how do you know (x-a)(x-b)=0?

Comment: @harry That is the definition of a root

Comment: Substitute in $a$ into LHS. Then it becomes $(a-a)(a-b) = 0\cdot(a-b) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks~ so root can be (x-a)(x-b)~

Comment: wait, but why (x+a) (x+b) = 0 ?

Comment: If you took $(x+a)(x+b) = 0$, then the roots would be $x=-a$ and $x=-b$ instead. This is because if you substitute (either of ) these two values in, you will observe that the LHS really resolves into $0$.

Comment: but it will become 
x^2 - 5x + 7 + i = 0

Comment: Then that will be the quadratic equation you were looking for. :)

Comment: really? i thought the answer is 
x^2 + (-5+i)x + 8 - i = 0
(but maybe the answer sheet is wrong)

Comment: You might want to try expanding it out again. Hold on, I'll improve my answer to show you a shortcut.

Comment: I believe the answer sheet is incorrect. WolframAlpha verifies : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+-+5x+%2B+7+%2B+i

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%2B%28-5%2Bi%29x%2B8-i%3D0

erm i think the answer sheet is correct for some reason

Comment: There was a typo in your question - The second root should be $3-2i$

Comment: Oh Okie :D thank you, sorry for the trouble

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13496/discussion-between-harry-and-yiyuan-lee)

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want a polynomial $p(x)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ of degree $n$ with roots $a_1,...,a_n$ we have $p(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_n)$ (where $a_i$ are not necessarily distinct - corresponding to roots of multiplicity). It is clear that each $a_i$ is in fact a root because $p(a_i)=(a_i-a_1)\cdots(a_i-a_i)\cdots(a_i-a_n)=0$.